# R: Moving average length of time between two dates

Tags: r

I have a dataset of observations with start and end dates. I would like to calculate the moving average difference between the start and end dates.

I've included an example dataset below.

```
require(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3), 
                 start=c("2019-01-01","2019-01-10", "2019-01-05"),
                 end=c("2019-02-01", "2019-01-15", "2019-01-10"))
df[,c("start", "end")] <- lapply(df[,c("start", "end")], as.Date)
```

```
id   start         end
1    2019-01-01    2019-02-01
2    2019-01-10    2019-01-15
3    2019-01-05    2019-01-10
```

The overall date ranges are `2019-01-01` to `2019-02-01`. I would like to calculate the average difference between the start and end dates for each of the dates in that range.

The result would look exactly like this. I've included the actual values for the averages that should show up:

```
date          avg
2019-01-01    0
2019-01-02    1
2019-01-03    2
2019-01-04    3
2019-01-05    4
2019-01-06    3
2019-01-07    4
2019-01-08    5
2019-01-09    6
2019-01-10    7
2019-01-11    5.5
    .         .
    .         .
    .         .
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4), 
                 start=c("2019-01-01","2019-01-01", "2019-01-10", "2019-01-05"),
                 end=c("2019-01-04", "2019-01-05", "2019-01-12", "2019-01-08"))
df[,c("start", "end")] <- lapply(df[,c("start", "end")], as.Date)
df
```

Returns:

```
id       start         end
1   2019-01-01  2019-01-04      
2   2019-01-01  2019-01-05      
3   2019-01-10  2019-01-12      
4   2019-01-05  2019-01-08
```

Then using the `group_by` function from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(start) %>% 
  summarize(avg=mean(end - start)) %>% 
  rename(date=start)
```

Returns:

```
date        avg
<time>      <time>
2019-01-01  3.5 days            
2019-01-05  3.0 days            
2019-01-10  2.0 days
```

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm looking to calculate. Ideally, I'd like to know for each date in the possible range of dates, was was the average time difference AT each date. One way to imagine this is a moving window where end date is the effective date until the actual end date.

Answer (score 0):

Editing the answer as per comments.

Creating the df:

```
require(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3), 
                 start=c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-10", "2019-01-05"),
                 end=c("2019-02-01", "2019-01-15", "2019-01-10"))
df[,c("start", "end")] <- lapply(df[,c("start", "end")], as.Date)
```

Create dates for every start-end combination:

```
#gives the list of all dates within start and end frames and calculates difference
datesList = lapply(1:nrow(df),function(i){
  dat = data_frame('date'=seq.Date(from=df$start[i],to=df$end[i],by=1),
                   'start'=df$start[i]) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(diff=date-start)
})
```

Finally, group_by the date and find avg to give output exactly as the one in the question:

```
finalDf = bind_rows(datesList) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(diff != 0) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(date) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(avg=mean(diff,na.rm=T))
```

The output thus becomes:

```
# A tibble: 31 x 2
   date       avg     
   <date>     <time>  
 1 2019-01-02 1.0 days
 2 2019-01-03 2.0 days
 3 2019-01-04 3.0 days
 4 2019-01-05 4.0 days
 5 2019-01-06 3.0 days
 6 2019-01-07 4.0 days
 7 2019-01-08 5.0 days
 8 2019-01-09 6.0 days
 9 2019-01-10 7.0 days
10 2019-01-11 5.5 days
# … with 21 more rows
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: I'm looking to get the average time difference at each point in the possible range of dates. That is, the end date should be each effective date until the actual end date.

Comment: @hvgupta, changed the answer as per comments. Check and let me know if it works.